# Reading from file each line to list in Python

Tags: python, file, encoding, character-encoding, special-characters

Here is my code:

```
with open(path) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print lines[0:5]
```

However I get many extra characters, for example:

```
['cat2\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 2\xc2\xa0 0', 'cat1\xc2\xa00.5\xc2\xa0 0', 'cat2\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 1\xc2\xa0 0', 'cat1\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 0\xc2\xa0 0', 'cat2\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0 0\xc2\xa0 3']
```

Why do I get them?

The original text file was this:

```
cat2   2  0
cat1 0.5  0
cat2   1  0
cat1   0  0
cat2   0  3
```

Comment: looks like you have strange chars in your file...

Comment: For whoever's trying to reopen this: All the ingredients to solve this are in the linked duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

`\xc2\xa0` is a `non-breaking space`. Replace it with regular spaces in the file.

This sequence appears in many encodings including `UTF-8`.

See more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)

Comment: Can you please add in which format these characters are found?